# Password checking algorithm

Tags: passwords, signature, key-exchange

I'm trying to reverse engineer a key exchange protocol which is based on the Diffie-Hellman key exchange scheme and faced with the following problem:

Let $g$ be the generator, $m$ the modulus.

Alice has a private key $a$ and computes her public key $A = g^a\pmod{m}$.
Bob has a private key $b$ and computes his public key $B = g^b\pmod{m}$.

During exchanges Bob generates password check signature:

- $C = f(A,B,password)$   where $f$ is cryptographic hash function.
- $D = f(m,g,password)$
- $X = \left(\left(D+A\right)\pmod{m}\right)^\left(C+b\right)\pmod{m} $

and then sends  $ f(X)$ to Alice.

Alice calculates $X$ on her side without $b$ and I can't figure out how.

Could somebody help me with the algorithm on Alice's side?

Comment: Is my interpretation of "You don't know what $\hspace{.02 in}f$ is and hope that something about $\hspace{.02 in}f$ can be $\hspace{.9 in}$ worked out from the fact that Alice can calculate **X**" correct? $\;$

Comment: No, I know that $f$ is a cryptographic hash function e.g. sha1, and I'm sure that Alice can calculate **X**, but she doesn't know **b** and Bob doesn't send value of **X** he sends $f(X)$. I think $X = f_1(K,password)$ where **K** is the shared secret between Alice and Bob. They both know **K** and password, so there must be an expression equivalent to **X** on the Alice's side.

Comment: it maybe that: $X \equiv (DA)^{C+b} \pmod{m}$, then it can be rewritten $X \equiv g^{(d+a)(C+b)} \pmod{m}$, so Alice can get $X$ by this way $X \equiv (g^CB)^{d+a}\pmod{m} $ , you can check that